# JavaScript ChartJS Array Issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, chart.js

I am currently trying to build a JavaScript application that creates metrics from a CSV. The CSV is saved in my file explorer and each column is extracted into its own, separate array. These arrays are set to be global arrays in an external JavaScript file referenced by the index.html file.

With all this in mind, the following is my JavaScript code:

```
function Wrap()
{
    "use strict";    

    top.date = [];
    top.numberCreated = [];
    top.numberResolved = [];
    top.totalCreated = [];
    top.totalResolved = [];
    top.numberOpen = [];
    top.numberclosed = [];

    this.data_csv = function()
    {          
        d3.csv("data.csv", function(data1)
        {                
            data1.forEach(function(obj) 
            {                                            
                top.date.push(obj.date.toString());
                top.numberCreated.push(obj.n_create.toString());
                numberResolved.push(obj.n_resolve.toString());
                totalCreated.push(obj.total_create.toString());
                totalResolved.push(obj.total_resolve.toString());
                numberOpen.push(obj.n_open.toString());
                numberclosed.push(obj.n_close.toString());                
            });     
            console.log(date); 
            console.log(numberCreated);         

        }); 
    }; 

    this.lineChartData = 
    {                    
        labels : date,
        datasets: [
            {
                fillColor: "rgba(77, 175, 124,1)",              
                strokeColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
                pointColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",             
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                data : numberCreated
            }
        ]
    };       

    this.barChartData = {
        labels : ["1/4/2016", "1/5/2016", "1/6/2016", "1/7/2016", "1/8/2016", "1/11/2016", "1/12/2016", "1/13/2016", "1/14/2016",
                  "1/15/2016", "1/19/2016", "1/20/2016", "1/27/2016", "1/29/2016", "2/5/2016", "2/9/2016", "2/11/2016", "2/12/2016",
                  "2/16/2016", "2/22/2016", "2/23/2016"],
        datasets : [
            {
                fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
                highlightFill: "#000",
                highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data : ["1", "1", "10", "1", "8", "1", "2", "3", "2", "3", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "3", "2", "1", "1", "1", "7"]
            }            
        ]

    };

    this.doughnutData =
    [
        {
            value: 300,
            color:"#F7464A",
            highlight: "#FF5A5E",
            label: "Red"
        },
        {
            value: 50,
            color: "#46BFBD",
            highlight: "#5AD3D1",
            label: "Green"
        },
        {
            value: 100,
            color: "#FDB45C",
            highlight: "#FFC870",
            label: "Yellow"
        },
        {
            value: 40,
            color: "#949FB1",
            highlight: "#A8B3C5",
            label: "Grey"
        },
        {
            value: 120,
            color: "#4D5360",
            highlight: "#616774",
            label: "Dark Grey"
        }

    ]
};

window.onload = function(){
    var wrap = new Wrap();
    wrap.data_csv();
    console.log(wrap.date);
    console.log(wrap.numberCreated);
    var linectx = document.getElementById("linecanvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myLine = new Chart(linectx).Line(wrap.lineChartData, {
        responsive : true
    });

    var barctx = document.getElementById("barcanvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myBar = new Chart(barctx).Bar(wrap.barChartData, {
        responsive : true
    });

    var doughnutctx = document.getElementById("doughnutcanvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myDoughnut = new Chart(doughnutctx).Doughnut(wrap.doughnutData, {
        responsive : true
    });

};
```

The current issue that I am facing with the code is that the top.date = []; and
top.numberCreated = []; arrays are null at line 42 and 51 respectively. This is odd because the two arrays are filled with correct data until this point. Would you guys be able to see whats going on in my code and where I have it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just fixed the issue myself with the following code:

```
function Wrap()
{
    "use strict";    

    //var randomScalingFactor = function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()*100)};
    top.date = [];
    top.numberCreated = [];
    top.numberResolved = [];
    top.totalCreated = [];
    top.totalResolved = [];
    top.numberOpen = [];
    top.numberClosed = [];

    this.data_csv = function()
    {
        //var parse = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y").parse; 
        var wrapperArray = [];           
        d3.csv("data.csv", function(data1)
        {                    
            /*var dataset = data.map(function(d)
            {*/
            data1.forEach(function(obj) 
            {                                            
                date.push(obj.date.toString());
                numberCreated.push(obj.n_create.toString());
                numberResolved.push(obj.n_resolve.toString());
                totalCreated.push(obj.total_create.toString());
                totalResolved.push(obj.total_resolve.toString());
                numberOpen.push(obj.n_open.toString());
                numberClosed.push(obj.n_close.toString());                
            });     
            console.log(date); 
            console.log(numberCreated);         
            /*});*/                    
        });
        wrapperArray.push(date); 
        wrapperArray.push(numberCreated);
        wrapperArray.push(numberResolved);
        wrapperArray.push(totalCreated);
        wrapperArray.push(totalResolved);
        wrapperArray.push(numberOpen);
        wrapperArray.push(numberClosed);
        return wrapperArray; 
    }; 


};

window.onload = function(){
    //new outer()).inner()
    var wrap = new Wrap();
    var arrayHolder = wrap.data_csv();

    top.date = arrayHolder[0];
    top.numberCreated = arrayHolder[1];
    top.numberResolved = arrayHolder[2];
    top.totalCreated = arrayHolder[3];
    top.totalResolved = arrayHolder[4];
    top.numberOpen = arrayHolder[5];
    top.numberClosed = arrayHolder[6];

    this.lineChartData = 
    {                    
        labels : top.date,
        datasets: [
            {
                fillColor: "rgba(77, 175, 124,1)",              
                strokeColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
                pointColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",             
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                data : top.numberCreated
            }
        ]
    };       

    this.barChartData = {
        labels : ["1/4/2016", "1/5/2016", "1/6/2016", "1/7/2016", "1/8/2016", "1/11/2016", "1/12/2016", "1/13/2016", "1/14/2016",
                  "1/15/2016", "1/19/2016", "1/20/2016", "1/27/2016", "1/29/2016", "2/5/2016", "2/9/2016", "2/11/2016", "2/12/2016",
                  "2/16/2016", "2/22/2016", "2/23/2016"],
        datasets : [
            {
                fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
                highlightFill: "#000",
                highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data : ["1", "1", "10", "1", "8", "1", "2", "3", "2", "3", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "3", "2", "1", "1", "1", "7"]
            }            
        ]

    };

    this.doughnutData =
    [
        {
            value: 300,
            color:"#F7464A",
            highlight: "#FF5A5E",
            label: "Red"
        },
        {
            value: 50,
            color: "#46BFBD",
            highlight: "#5AD3D1",
            label: "Green"
        },
        {
            value: 100,
            color: "#FDB45C",
            highlight: "#FFC870",
            label: "Yellow"
        },
        {
            value: 40,
            color: "#949FB1",
            highlight: "#A8B3C5",
            label: "Grey"
        },
        {
            value: 120,
            color: "#4D5360",
            highlight: "#616774",
            label: "Dark Grey"
        }

    ]

    console.log(top.date);
    console.log(top.numberCreated);
    var linectx = document.getElementById("linecanvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myLine = new Chart(linectx).Line(lineChartData, {
        responsive : true
    });

    var barctx = document.getElementById("barcanvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myBar = new Chart(barctx).Bar(barChartData, {
        responsive : true
    });

    var doughnutctx = document.getElementById("doughnutcanvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myDoughnut = new Chart(doughnutctx).Doughnut(doughnutData, {
        responsive : true
    });

};
```